# How to get element's id of another view SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have 3 views say first,second & third. I need to access a vertical layout's id of second view from first view. For which I have used `sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1--spend_layt");` to retrieve it. It works but when I navigate to third view & come back, id changes to `__xmlview28--spend_layt` & the control not works. How to fix this?

**EDIT :**

First.view.xml

`<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="budgetspend.controller.First" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    displayBlock="true">
    <App id="BA_APP">
        <pages>
            <HBox width="100%" height="100%" id="header_container">
                <items>
                    <Image class="logo" src="../images/logo_new.png"/>
                    <Image class="header" src="../images/header-bg.png"/>
                    <html:ul class="tab">
                        <html:li>
                            <html:a id="onBud" class="tablinks active">Tab 1
                        </html:li>
                        <html:li>
                            <html:a id="onSpend" class="tablinks">Tab 2</html:a>
                        </html:li>
                    </html:ul>
                    <mvc:XMLView viewName="budgetspend.view.second"/>
                </items>
            </HBox>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>`

In the second view, I use 2 vertical layouts. one for tab 1 & another for tab 2. Only one visible at a time. Tab click events are written in First.controller.js. I don't know how to access ID's of vertical layouts(in second view) from First.

> I am just exploring how standard html will work on SAPUI5 as I am aware of using `sap.m.IconTab`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the use case. Using ID's is not a good practice in UI5.

Comment: In addition to that, as long as you don't destroy your views, ID's should remain the same (destroying views is another bad practice)

Comment: No I am not destroying views. I just set visibility.  ID changes when I leave the page & come back. they are generated dynamically.

Comment: Can you please evaluate my answer? It's also not very clear what your question is! On the first part of the question you ask how to access the vertical layout's ID from the first view, and on the edited part, you want to know how to hide/show vertical layouts in the second controller. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Yal The updated answer serves your purpose. Let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to create class  & also adding setters/getters in SAPUI. It would be helpful if you provide some refrence/example.

Comment: @Yal please use the @ sign to notify the people you're talking to. In my example, the class file is already there. It's a copy/paste job. I now added a getter/setter example for you. Just replicate to Controller 2 & 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are facing is due to the dynamic creation of elements. Every time you leave a screen and goes back into it, the items are regenerated, but they can't have the same ID, since they were used before.

One solution to this is to create a `Utils` folder, and create an object, let's say `UIHelper`.

This file would look like this:

```
jQuery.sap.declare('my.app.Utils.UIHelper');

my.app.Utils.UIHelper = {
  controllerInstance1 : null,
  controllerInstance2 : null,
  controllerInstance3 : null,

 //Add "getters and setters" for each of these attributes (repeat for Controller 2 & 3)
 setControllerInstance1 : function(oController){
      this.controllerInstance1 = oController;
  },
 getControllerInstance1 : function(){
    return this.controllerInstance1;
  }

};
```

Now, at the controller file for each of your views, you add the following line at the top of the file:

```
jQuery.sap.require('my.app.Utils.UIHelper');
```

And on the `onInit` event of those controllers, you set the controller instance on the `UIHelper` object:

```
my.app.Utils.UIHelper.setControllerInstance1(this);
```

And when you want to get the different `views` from anywhere in the code, assuming that the `views` are assigned to one of the controllers, you can just use the following:

```
my.app.Utils.UIHelper.getControllerInstance1().getView();
```

***Update in my answer after the update on the question:***

To access the layout from the second view, you could do the following:

```
var layout = my.app.Utils.UIHelper.getControllerInstanceView2().byId('spend_layt');
```